# Combinatorics with poker hands

Tags: combinatorics

How many $5$-cards poker hands are there containing all $4$ suits?

Attempt at solution:
$$4\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{2}$$
(The amount of suits)

Is this correct? A friend thinks it should be $48(13^4)$. Would that be the correct answer instead?

Comment: You are correct, your friend is off by a factor of two, presumably because when they were choosing the two cards of the repeated suit, they forgot that order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend's answer is twice yours, but you are correct.

The difference is that your friend doubly counts the two arrangements of the two cards from the suit that is repeated, when they should only count once.

---

There are $4$ ways to choose which suit gets repeated. Given this, there are $$\binom{13}{2}$$ ways to choose the two cards from the repeated suit, and $13$ ways to choose the card from each of the remaining three suits. This gives

$$4 \cdot \binom{13}{2} \cdot 13^3 = 4 \cdot \frac{13 \cdot 12}{2} \cdot 13^3 = 24 \cdot 13^4$$

which is half of your friend's $48 \cdot 13^4$